# iCal (.ics) import to FullCalendar not showing any events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have been trying for some days now a way to import a `.ics` file from a url like google calendar.
I just can't seem to get it working for some reason.

The goal is to have a page with a calendar synced to multiple google calendars. I don't want to use the "googleCalendarId" because I want to attach resources and I saw that it only works with .ics or JSON feeds.

I tried changing/updating the libraries. I also tried all examples that I could find. I heard about CORS might be a problem and I'm unfamiliar to this so I tried the file on localhost, my domain online and others instead of the google URL, but it didn't work.

Here is my test code:

> 

```
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ical.js/1.4.0/ical.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/icalendar@5.5.1/main.global.min.js"></script>
 
 <script>
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
   var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
 
   var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
     initialView: "dayGridMonth",
     headerToolbar: {
       left: "prev,next today",
       center: "title",
       right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
     },
     //plugins: [DayGridPlugin, iCalendarPlugin],
     events: {
       url: "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/MyCalendarIdHere%40import.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics",
       format: "ics",
     },
   });
 
   calendar.render();
 });
 </script>
```

I tried other ways like JSON from a file and googleCalendarId with API key from gCloud and it worked just fine.

**-UPDATE-**
Thank you for the replies, i'm sorry i missed some important details.

1. So as for the *""I want to attach resources and I saw that it only works with .ics or JSON feeds"...where did you see that exactly?"*

As i mentioned i'm using FullCalendar, i don't know if there is others but i was mentioning (https://fullcalendar.io) and acording to their documentation in (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-and-events) to add resources to a event you simply need to add

`resourceId: 'id',`

on the event after you clarify the resource before, so i tried the code given in the documentation and it worked on json files i can't confirm on ics because i could never get any events from using ics from a local file or from a url, and this also didn't work for google calendar, upon further search i found this about the subject (https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3020) the admin moved the subject to (https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4825) which is basically the same method from the documentation, the fact that the issue is still open plus the multiple failed attempts led me to believe that it wasn't still implemented.

Here is the the code i was working on at the time:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
plugins: ['dayGrid', 'list','googleCalendar','iCalendarPlugin', 'resourceTimeline' ], defaultView: 'resourceTimelineDay',

header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'dayGridMonth,listYear'
},

displayEventTime: false,
googleCalendarApiKey: 'MYAPIKEY',
resources: [
  {
    id: 'a',
    title: 'Room A'
  },
  {
    id: 'b',
    title: 'Room B'
  }
],
eventSources: [
  {
    resourceId: 'a',
    googleCalendarId: 'calendar id',
    "className": 'a446',
  },
  {
    resourceId: 'b',
    googleCalendarId: 'calendar id',
    "className": 'a447',

  },
]

  });
calendar.render();
});
```

2. As for "*errors from the browser console, or evidence of problems*"

i never got any error from trying to import .ics (nor in xampp, Visual Code, the hosted webpage for the test) into fullcalendar it simply doesn't show any events as if the ics file is empty (which is not), or the script is completely ignoring the import ?

I basically used the same code from the GoogleCalendarId above but instead of "resources:" and "eventSources:" i used this piece of code:

```
events: {
  url: 'i can't post more than a specific number of urls so please use the url on the examples below ',
  format: 'ics'
},
```

About the "*Since we don't know your calendar ID or the real URL of your ics file, we cannot run your code to try and reproduce your problem*"

The url with the ics file is not really mine to share (containing personal info) so i decided not to, but that should not be a problem for anyone because i'm having this problem with all ics urls even the public holidays from google or other sources, but anyway i'm going to add one ics url with one of my files for anyone to test.

Example ics url that i have tried (https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/en.uk%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics)

My url (https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/90t5sm8mqsrjuq807nman5u3t9shike6%40import.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics) the settings on google are set to public on this file!

3. Here are some of the example codes i took inspiration (without sucess on the ics import):

https://codepen.io/manuel-valente/pen/rNpZoJP
https://codepen.io/bifrost04/pen/BEJbva

Comment: _"I want to attach resources and I saw that it only works with .ics or JSON feeds"_...where did you see that exactly? I can't think of a reason it would make any difference which type of source you use. The whole point of the event source architecture in fullCalendar is that the sources are interchangeable, and the received events are treated the same way by fullCalendar, no matter where they originate from

Comment: As for _"it didn't work"_, that's not a useful description we can use to help you fix anything. What debugging have you done? You need to find some information such as errors from the browser console, or evidence of problems with the request to the .ics file (which would be visible in your browser's Network tool) or something like that. Since we don't know your calendar ID or the real URL of your ics file, we cannot run your code to try and reproduce your problem, therefore you need to debug it thoroughly and explain to us precisely what is happening - we cannot really just guess. Thanks.

Comment: Just so you know I've seen your update, thanks, I don't have time to look into it in detail right now but I will try and get to it in a few days.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the mess i'm not very good at posting questions. If i find anything new i will keep updating the post.